# Unexpected Indent Python error

Tags: python, indentation

So whenever i use my cog i get the "Unexpected Indentation" error..

I've been trying to fix it for a while now but it STILL doesn't seem to work..

Code:

````
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def magik(self, ctx, url, url2=None):
"""Apply magik to Image(s)\n .magik image_url or .magik image_url image_url_2"""
try:
    print(url)
    extensions = ['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.JPG', '.PNG', '.JPEG']
    if any(x in url for x in extensions) and url2 is None:
        await self.bot.say("ok, applying magik")
        with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            location = '/root/discord/files/magik.jpg'
            async with session.get(url) as resp:
                data = await resp.read()
                with open(location, "wb") as f:
                    f.write(data)
    elif url2 is not None and any(x in url2 for x in extensions):
        await self.bot.say("ok, applying magik")
        with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            location = '/root/discord/files/magik.jpg'
            location2 = '/root/discord/files/magik2.jpg'
            async with session.get(url) as resp:
                data = await resp.read()
                with open(location, "wb") as f:
                    f.write(data)
            async with session.get(url2) as resp:
                data = await resp.read()
                with open(location2, "wb") as f:
                    f.write(data)
    else:
        await self.bot.say("Not an image!")
        return
    exif = {}
    image = wand.image.Image(filename='/root/discord/files/magik.jpg')
    exif.update((k[5:], v) for k, v in image.metadata.items()
        if k.startswith('exif:'))
    if url2 is not None:
        exif2 = {}
        image2 = wand.image.Image(filename='/root/discord/files/magik2.jpg')
        exif2.update((k[5:], v) for k, v in image2.metadata.items()
            if k.startswith('exif:'))
    img = wand.image.Image(filename='/root/discord/files/magik.jpg')
    print(img.size)
    i = img.clone()
    r = random.randint(1,4)
    if url2 is not None:
        with wand.image.Image(filename='/root/discord/files/magik2.jpg') as B:
            B.clone()
            B.liquid_rescale(width=int(B.width*0.5), height=int(B.height*0.5), delta_x=1, rigidity=0)
            B.liquid_rescale(width=int(B.width*1.5), height=int(B.height*1.5), delta_x=2, rigidity=0)

            with wand.image.Image(filename='/root/discord/files/magik.jpg') as A:
                A.clone()
                A.transform(resize='800x800>')
                A.liquid_rescale(width=int(A.width*0.5), height=int(A.height*0.5), delta_x=1, rigidity=0)
                A.liquid_rescale(width=int(A.width*1.5), height=int(A.height*1.5), delta_x=2, rigidity=0)
                A.resize(A.width, A.height)
                A.composite_channel('default_channels', A, 'over', 0, 0 )
                A.composite_channel('default_channels', B, 'over', 0, 0 )
                A.save(filename='/root/discord/files/magik_.png')                
    else:
        params = random.uniform(0.5, 2)
        i.transform(resize='800x800>')
        i.liquid_rescale(width=int(i.width*0.5), height=int(i.height*0.5), delta_x=1, rigidity=0)
        i.liquid_rescale(width=int(i.width*1.5), height=int(i.height*1.5), delta_x=2, rigidity=0)
        i.resize(i.width, i.height)
        # i.rotate(90 * r)
        # i.negate()
        i.save(filename='/root/discord/files/magik_.png')
    print(exif)
    if len(str(exif)) <= 2000 and url2 is None:
        await self.bot.say("Exif Data: ```{0}```".format(str(exif)))
    elif url2 is not None and len(str(exif)) <= 2000 and len(str(exif2)) <= 2000:
        await self.bot.say("Exif Data Image 1: ```{0}```".format(str(exif)))
        await self.bot.say("Exif Data Image 2: ```{0}```".format(str(exif2)))
    else:
        await self.bot.say("Exif Data too long, truncated")
    await self.bot.send_file(ctx.message.channel, '/root/discord/files/magik_.png')
except Exception as e:
    await self.bot.say(code.format(type(e).__name__ + ': ' + str(e)))
````

Help is appreciated as i can't seem to fix this error.

Comment: Seems as if the indentation broke again when you inserted the into SO syntax. Please get the leading four spaces right, otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: Have you tried to de-indent and reindent all your lines of code in a consistent way ?
Sometimes it worked for me, mostly when I copy-pasted code from a text editor to another.

Comment: An error I often met is the mixing of tabulations and "4 spaces" in the indentations because of the use of different editors. Your editor may have an option to fix it or you can select a true tabulation and do a replace all to 4 spaces.

Comment: What editor do you guys use? Right now im just using Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

It is likely a problem of using mixed tabs and spaces. Depending on the editor you are using, you may have to go to your editor preferences and establish a means to setup "tabs as spaces".